# ¿error utilizando libreria angular publicada previamente por mi?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Elaboré una librería angular de prueba que tiene un servicio y solo hace una suma.
Después de publicarla en Azure Artifacts con Azure DevOps la descargué desde otro proyecto de prueba para utilizarla, la importé desde los archivos app.modeule y app.component...

Ya validé el funcionamiento del servicio antes de compilarlo y validé el funcionamiento del proyecto de prueba antes de utilizar el servicio de suma

El sistema me genera este error a la hora de subir el servidor (ng serve)

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/operaciones/src/lib/operaciones.service.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: .../Wiki/PruebasDeConcepto/proyecto-prueba-five/node_modules/operaciones/src/lib/operaciones.service.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/run/media/mauricio/EEAC581BAC57DCA1/Usuarios de Linux/MauricioPulgarin/Empresa/Wiki/PruebasDeConcepto/proyecto-prueba-five/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at /run/media/mauricio/EEAC581BAC57DCA1/Usuarios de Linux/MauricioPulgarin/Empresa/Wiki/PruebasDeConcepto/proyecto-prueba-five/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:43:31
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las versiones de angular pueden diferir, me dices que lo subiste a azure, por lo cual `azure` debe tener algo que compile `angular` quiza resulte ser que tu version local es mas moderna que la version del servidor, por ende te da errores, o incluso puede ser al contrario, por ejemplo yo en `ionic4 (angular)` y una app que estoy haciendo me dio una cantidad absurda de errores al tratar de actualizar a `ionic5`, lo curioso es que la mayoria de errores eran de **angular** y no de `ionic`, por ende las versiones de angular son muy importantes.

Comment: PD: al final decidi no pasarme a `ionic5`, puede que por temas de seguridad valiera la pena, pero que me genere 55 errores nuevos solo por pasarme es absurdo.

Comment: Analizanado el stack noto estos dos puntos `[...] is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`  y `[...] TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library.`. Por lo que todo indica que tu librería no está transpilada, publicaste tus archivos `.ts` y no los archivos transpilados  `.js`. Es correcto?

Comment: En teoría, en el pipeline transpilé antes de publicar. El procedimiento lo realicé con una linea que dice lo siguiente:
ng-packagr -p projects/operaciones/ng-package.json
A su vez, esta linea nos lleva al ng-package.json que está en la ruta **projects/operaciones**
...todo esto lo hice siguiendo un tutorial.